# Where to add a Shell Bar control in an XML view when using SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am new to OpenUI5/SAPUI5 and trying to build my first app with it. It will be a standalone app and I am struggling with the Shell Bar control, which I want to add to my views.

As I understand things, I write my root view which contains an App control, and then I swap in and out my individual views using the pages aggregation of the App control (by using a router).

Now I want the Shell Bar to be "stuck" to the top, which means it cannot be part of the individual pages, as this would also swap out the Shell Bar and I would have to include it in every view that is managed by the router. It also feels "wrong" to have the Shell Bar not be part of the root view.

I tried different approaches for "nailing" the Shell Bar to the top of my view, but depending on my different tries, I end up with various results, all of which are not what I intend to do.

**Example 1** (Shell Bar is a child of App outside its pages aggregation):

```
    <Shell>
        <App>
            <f:ShellBar title="Funky Title"
                        showNotifications="true"
                        notificationsNumber="2"
                        homeIcon="./static/logo.png">
                <f:menu>
                    <Menu>
                        <MenuItem text="{i18n>learnMenuEntry}" icon="sap-icon://e-learning"/>
                        <MenuItem text="{i18n>catalogMenuEntry}" icon="sap-icon://course-book"/>
                        <MenuItem text="{i18n>statisticsMenuEntry}" icon="sap-icon://line-chart"/>
                        <MenuItem text="{i18n>settingsMenuEntry}" icon="sap-icon://settings"/>
                    </Menu>
                </f:menu>
                <f:profile>
                    <f:Avatar initials="UI"/>
                </f:profile>

            </f:ShellBar>

            <pages>
                <Page title="{i18n>homePageTitle}">
                    <content>
                       [ ... ]
                    </content>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
    </Shell>
```

This shows the Shell Bar at the top, but whatever is part of the Page control is not shown at all. I think adding controls outside of the  aggregation breaks the App control.

**Example 2** (Shell Bar is outside of Shell):

```
<mvc:View
        controllerName="webhrt.controller.App"
        xmlns="sap.m"
        xmlns:f="sap.f"
        xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
        displayBlock="true">


    <f:ShellBar title="Funky title"
                secondTitle="Startseite"
                showNotifications="true"
                notificationsNumber="2"
                homeIcon="./static/logo.png">
        <f:menu>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem text="{i18n>learnMenuEntry}" icon="sap-icon://e-learning"/>
                <MenuItem text="{i18n>catalogMenuEntry}" icon="sap-icon://course-book"/>
                <MenuItem text="{i18n>statisticsMenuEntry}" icon="sap-icon://line-chart"/>
                <MenuItem text="{i18n>settingsMenuEntry}" icon="sap-icon://settings"/>
            </Menu>
        </f:menu>
        <f:profile>
            <f:Avatar initials="UI"/>
        </f:profile>

    </f:ShellBar>

    <Shell>
        <App>
            <pages>
                <Page title="{i18n>homePageTitle}">
                    <content>
                        [ ... ]
                        </Panel>
                    </content>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

This somehow works, but because the Shell Bar lives "outside" the Shell, it is not part of the letterboxing which limits the width of the page. It covers the whole width of the screen.

I also tried adding the Shell Bar as a child of the Shell control, but this is not supported as per the documentation for the Shell control, which only allows an App control as its child.

What am I missing? I also browsed through the examples on the OpenUI5 website, but the documentation on the use of the Shell Bar control is rather scarce.

Comment: Have you checked the following samles? In the source code you should be able to see their hierarchy. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.f.ShellBar In one example the `ShellBar` is in the `header` aggregation of a `Page`

Comment: Also a Fiori Launchpad works like you explained in your second scenario. The ShellHeader is full width, but the apps are letterboxed.

Comment: Thanks @Marc, I was aware of the `header` aggregation, but that would again make the `ShellBar` part of the `Page`, which is not what I want (as it would be swapped out when I change pages using a router).

Nevertheless, your second answer regarding the Fiori Launchpad was an excellent hint. I was not aware that the `ShellBar` in a real Fiori app covers the whole width of the screen, so using my 2nd example above (having the `ShellBar` outside of the `Shell`) seems to be the correct way of using a `ShellBar`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

Here is App.view.xml

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:f="sap.f" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="cis.gp.controller.App" height="100%">
<Shell showLogout="false" appWidthLimited="false" >
    <App busy="{appView>/busy}" busyIndicatorDelay="0" height="100%" autoFocus="false">
        <Page id="app" class="sapMBrandingBar-CTX sapUiResponsivePadding--header sapUiResponsivePadding--content">
            <customHeader>
                <f:ShellBar title="{i18n>appTitle}">
                    <f:profile>
                        <Avatar src="sap-icon://sap-ui5" />
                      </f:profile>                    
                </f:ShellBar>
            </customHeader>
        </Page>        
    </App>
</Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

In your manifest routing,

```
"routing": {
    "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "async": true,
        "viewPath": "kk.view",
        "controlAggregation": "content",
        "controlId": "app",
        "clearControlAggregation": false
    },
```

Note that controlAggregation is 'content' (as Page is our root control now)